# How to find the current available version of a Cordova plugin

Tags: cordova

I'm using a Cordova plugin - I know that an up-coming version of the plugin has a fix that I need, but at the moment I'm locked into using an older version of the plugin from before the bug was introduced.

Is there a way to find out what the current version of a plugin is without uninstalling it and reinstalling it (and then having to reinstall the older one if it's not been updated yet)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [cordova-check-plugins](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-check-plugins) to list both the locally installed version(s) and the most recent available remote version(s):

```
$ cordova-check-plugins
```

[image]

It will also allow you to automatically or interactively update installed plugins.

Comment: This is great but actually it doesn't quite solve my problem - because I have the plugin in question locked at "cordova-plugin-camera@1.2.0" it actually just shows that as the remote version available too.

Comment: Actually (reading the docs) it seems I could use 'cordova-check-plugins --unconstrain-versions' to get over this. But oddly the plugin in question doesn't actually appear in the list at all if I do that. Close though!

Answer (score 3):

you can try this command on command line

`cordova plugin ls`

[image]

let me know if its not working

Answer (score -1):

You can use **package.json** file to check the current version of the cordova plugin.